# The menu didn't appear and listview unclickable

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-menu

Thank you for helping me. The menu didn't appear and the list view in the recycler view is unclickable.

This is the menu part.

```
public class QuizListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_list);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerBView);
    new FirebaseDatabaseHelper().readQuiz(new FirebaseDatabaseHelper.DataStatus() {
        @Override
        public void DataIsLoaded(List<Quiz> quizzes, List<String> keys) {
            new RecyclerConfig().setConfig(mRecyclerView, QuizListActivity.this, quizzes, keys);
        }

        @Override
        public void DataIsInserted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void DataIsUpdated() {

        }

        @Override
        public void DataIsDeleted() {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quizlistmenu, menu);
    if(user!=null) {
        menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
        menu.getItem(1).setVisible(true);
        menu.getItem(2).setVisible(true);
    }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(user!=null) {
        menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
        menu.getItem(1).setVisible(true);
        menu.getItem(2).setVisible(true);
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.new_book:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, NewQuestionActivity.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.user_approval:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Approval.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.signout:
            mAuth.signOut();
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            RecyclerConfig.logout();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is the menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/new_book"
        android:title="New Question" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/user_approval"
        android:title="Registered User" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/signout"
        android:title="Sign Out" />
</menu>
```

This is the Recycler part.

```
public class RecyclerConfig
{
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private static FirebaseUser user;
    private Context mContext;
    private QuizAdapter mQuizAdapter;
    public void setConfig(RecyclerView mRecyclerView, Context context, List<Quiz> quizzes, List<String> keys)
    {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mContext = context;
        mQuizAdapter = new QuizAdapter(quizzes, keys);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mQuizAdapter);
    }
    class QuizItemView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView mquestion,mans1,mans2,mans3,mans4,mcorrect,mcategoryid;

    private String key;

    public QuizItemView(ViewGroup parent)
    {
        super(LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                .inflate(R.layout.quizlistitem, parent, false));

        mquestion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.questiontv);
        mans1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ans1tv);
        mans2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ans2tv);
        mans3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ans3tv);
        mans4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ans4tv);
        mcorrect = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.correcttv);
        mcategoryid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categorytv);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(user!=null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, QuizDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("key", key);
                    intent.putExtra("question", mquestion.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("answer1", mans1.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("answer2", mans2.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("answer3", mans3.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("answer3", mans4.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("answer3", mcorrect.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("categoryid", mcategoryid.getText().toString());

                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                /*else
                {
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, SignInActivity.class));
                }*/

            }
        });
    }

    public void bind(Quiz quizzes, String key)
    {
        mquestion.setText(quizzes.getQuestion());
        mans1.setText(quizzes.getAnswer1());
        mans2.setText(quizzes.getAnswer2());
        mans3.setText(quizzes.getAnswer3());
        mans4.setText(quizzes.getAnswer4());
        mcorrect.setText(quizzes.getCorrect());
        mcategoryid.setText(quizzes.getCategoryid());
        this.key = key;
    }
}
class QuizAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuizItemView>
{
    private List<Quiz> mQuizList;
    private List<String> mKeys;

    public QuizAdapter(List<Quiz> mQuizList, List<String> mKeys) {
        this.mQuizList = mQuizList;
        this.mKeys = mKeys;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public QuizItemView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new QuizItemView(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull QuizItemView holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(mQuizList.get(position), mKeys.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mQuizList.size();
    }
}

public static void logout()
{
    user = null;
}
}
```

This is the login / register part.

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MaterialEditText edtNewEmail,edtNewPassword,edtnewName, edtnewAge, edtnewAddress, edtStatus; // for register
MaterialEditText edtEmail,edtPassword; //for Signin

Button btnRegister,btnSignIn;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;


FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference users;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    users = database.getReference("User");

    edtEmail = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
    edtPassword = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

    btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signInBtn);
    btnRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.regBtn);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showSignUpDialog();
        }
    });

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signIn(edtEmail.getText().toString(),edtPassword.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}

private void signIn(final String user, final String pwd) {
    users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.child(user).exists())
            {
                if(!user.isEmpty())
                {
                 User login = dataSnapshot.child(user).getValue(User.class);
                 if(login.getPassword().equals(pwd))
                 {
                     Common.currentUser = login;
                         if(login.getStatus().equals("Admin"))
                         {
                             mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(edtEmail.getText().toString(),
                                     edtPassword.getText().toString());
                             Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "User signed in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,QuizListActivity.class);
                             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                             startActivity(intent);
                             finish(); return;
                         }
                         else if(login.getStatus().equals("User") && login.getApproval().equals("Y"))
                             {
                                 Intent homeactivity = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,Home.class);
                                 startActivity(homeactivity);
                                 finish();
                             }
                         else if(login.getStatus().equals("User") && login.getApproval().equals("N"))
                         {
                             Intent adminactivity = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,Home.class);
                             startActivity(adminactivity);
                             finish();
                         }

                 }
                 else
                     Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"Login Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"Please fill in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"User doesn't exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void showSignUpDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignInActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Sign Up");
    //alertDialog.setMessage("Please fill full information");

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View activity_register = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_register,null);

    //edtNewUserName = (MaterialEditText)activity_register.findViewById(R.id.edtNewUserName);
    edtNewEmail = (MaterialEditText)activity_register.findViewById(R.id.edtNewEmail);
    edtNewPassword = (MaterialEditText)activity_register.findViewById(R.id.edtNewPassword);
    edtnewName =  (MaterialEditText)activity_register.findViewById(R.id.edtnewName);
    edtnewAge = (MaterialEditText)activity_register.findViewById(R.id.edtnewAge);
    edtnewAddress = (MaterialEditText)activity_register.findViewById(R.id.edtnewAddress);
    edtStatus = (MaterialEditText)activity_register.findViewById(R.id.edtStatus);

    alertDialog.setView(activity_register);
    //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp);

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            final User user = new User(edtNewEmail.getText().toString(),
                    edtNewPassword.getText().toString(),edtnewName.getText().toString(),
                    edtnewAge.getText().toString(),edtnewAddress.getText().toString(),edtStatus.getText().toString(),
                    "N");
            users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.child(user.getEmail()).exists())
                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"User already exist.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                    {
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(user.getStatus()).exists() && user.getStatus() == "Admin")
                        {
                            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(edtNewEmail.getText().toString(),
                                    edtNewPassword.getText().toString())
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                                            {
                                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")
                                                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(user);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        else {
                            users.child(user.getEmail())
                                    .setValue(user);
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "User registered.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();

}

}
```

The login and register works well then after login the list recycler view is shown accurately but the menu didn't appear and the recycler view is unclickable.

For the menu, it previously stated that a null reference or something.

Comment: try to move `FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();` from `onCreate()` into `onCreateOptionsMenu()` .. please let me know if that works

Comment: Zain, It crash and this error came out : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference

Comment: @ImanMardhiah what line it errors ?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, which is why menu didn't appear because you didn't initialize the `FirebaseUser`. You need to initiliaze it at method `onCreate`.

at Class.

```
private FirebaseUser user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_list);
   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
   user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
}
```

next, at your `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quizlistmenu, menu);
    if(user!=null) {
        menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
        menu.getItem(1).setVisible(true);
        menu.getItem(2).setVisible(true);
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```